# Issue Sending data to mysql in android studio

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I am currently building an app for my university project and I am well and truly stuck. I am currently trying to send data from my apps sign up page to my Mysql database, I have gotten as far as being able to connect due to error logs showing that a connection was successful but no data is being sent to the database?

I have tried multiple ways of sending the data through php but it doesn't seem to make any difference. I was hoping maybe someone could point out my mistake and help me get past this hurdle I have been stuck on for so long.

**Signup.java**

```
package com.example.projectv1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class SignUp extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView nxtPage;
    EditText Fname;
    EditText Lname;
    EditText Email;
    EditText Password;
    EditText RePassword;
    private String sendURL = "https://tg322.brighton.domains/AppPHP/get_data.php";
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private static final String TAG = SignUp.class.getSimpleName();
    int success;
    private String TAG_SUCCESS = "Success";
    private String TAG_MESSAGE = "Message";
    private String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
        nxtPage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.NextPage);
        Fname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFName);
        Lname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLName);
        Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        RePassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextRePassword);

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        nxtPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent startActivity = new Intent(SignUp.this, HomePage.class);

                startActivity(startActivity);
                sendData();
            }
        });

    }

    //public void GetData(){

     //   TempFname = Fname.getText().toString();

     //   TempLname = Lname.getText().toString();

     //   TempEmail = Email.getText().toString();

     //   TempPassword = Password.getText().toString();

  //  }

    private void sendData(){
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, sendURL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
            try{
                JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(response);
                success = jobj.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if(success == 1){
                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, jobj.getString(TAG_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, jobj.getString(TAG_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Error Occured " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("F_Name" , Fname.getText().toString());
                params.put("L_Name" , Lname.getText().toString());
                params.put("Email" , Email.getText().toString());
                params.put("Password" , Password.getText().toString());
                return params;
            }
        };
        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, 1, 1.0f));
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

}
```

**DatabaseConfig.php**

```
<?php


$HostName = "localhost";


$HostUser = "tg322_admin";


$HostPass = "1234";


$DatabaseName = "tg322_AndroidAppDatabase";

$con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);
if(!$con){
    echo "Error occured in connection";
}
?>
```

**get_data.php**

```
<?php

include "DatabaseConfig.php";
class user{}
$fname = ($_POST['F_Name']);
 $lname = ($_POST['L_Name']);
 $email = ($_POST['Email']);
 $pass = ($_POST['Password']);
 $query = "INSERT INTO 'Login_Details' ('id' , 'F_Name' , 'L_Name' , 'Email' , 'Password') values (NULL, '".$fname."' , '".$lname."' , '".$email."' , '".$pass."')";

 mysqli_query($con,$query);

if($query){
    $response=new user();
    $response->success=1;
    $response->message="Successfully uploaded";
    die(json_encode($response));
}else{
    $response=new user();
    $response->success=0;
    $response->message="Failed to upload";
    die(json_encode($response));
}
 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This is the result when running my app:

[Error Occured org.json.JSONException: No value for Success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzHCK.png)

**Edit**

After adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to both php scripts, I am confident  that the error does not lie with the php code as no error is being reported. `{"success":1,"message":"Successfully uploaded"}` This is the response from my php code so I am connecting to the database successfully but I am unsure what the issue is with my android studio code.

Comment: Check your php code for errors. Log your server side response before you try to use this response.  Better in a web browser,  and ensure  you are getting the response you need.  If you are not getting the response try setting error_reporting on for your php code.

Comment: I have added error_reporting on my php code and I am receiving no errors. {"success":1,"message":"Successfully uploaded"} this is the message that get_data.php is responding with meaning that my php code is working as intended. I know now that it is an issue with my android studio code but I am not sure where to start with that.

Comment: tdid you try setting a breakpoint, or log the response in the onResponse in Volley.

Comment: Where would you recommend adding a break point and how do I log the response in onResponse?

Comment: I have added a break point and it looks as if the app continuously times out when trying to connect?

Comment: well, what does google tell you about your above two question. At stackoverflow, you are encouraged to ask questions which you can't find answers to (Note this does not mean that you are not allowed to ask if an answer IS THERE on google). When I was new to SO, I thought that it is too hard to ask questions on stackoverflow for a newcomer. However that is not the case. Over time I learnt that StackOverflow has answer to almost EVERY question. Follow guidelines to ask questions.You will get a lot of Aha! moments while you are writing your questions in proper format.

Comment: Set a breakpoint after `public void onResponse(String response) {` . Read about Log here (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log)